# Save/convert geopackage to DWG

Tags: qgis, geopackage, dxf, autocad, dwg

Is there a way to save data from a geopackage to a DXF/DWG without saving each layer to a DXF in the process and then stitching them together in CAD?

Comment: Are you asking how [`export project to DXF`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#create-dxf-files) works?

Comment: Thank you. I could have thought of that myself.